# How restore /var/lib/mysql after i delete it?

Tags: 10.04, mysql

How restore /var/lib/mysql (UBUNTU 10.04) after i delete it?

History:

1. delete /var/lib/mysql folder
2. paste new /var/lib/mysql folder with wrong files
3. delete again /var/lib/mysql folder
4. clean + reinstall mysql

result after reinstall:/var/lib/mysql folder not exist

Thanks,
Yosef

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Restoring `/var/lib/mysql` can be done by putting back a backup. If you did not have a backup, you've lost your database. The only thing that can be done is reinstalling the MySQL server:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install mysql-server-5.1
```

FYI, the MySQL root password is stored in `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`.

Comment: Thanks, I run the command but i see in shell: Unpacking replacement mysql-server-5.1 ...  and shell not write after that nothing just waiting for something

Comment: Have you removed your `/var/lib/mysql` directory before reinstalling? If possible, remove (or rename) `/etc/mysql` to something else and try again.